# How do I graph this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, graphing-functions

$$y\le x\le \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Graph: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3C%3Dx%3C%3Dsqrt%281-y%5E2%29

How would I approach this problem?

I graphed $0\le x\le \sqrt{1-y^2}$ easily, but this one is tougher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $x=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ is the equation of the righthand half of the unit circle; the region in which $x\le\sqrt{1-y^2}$ is therefore the region extending horizontall to the left from this semicircle. The inequality $y\le x$ specifies the points lying to the right of the line $x=y$. Put the two together, and you have the blue region shown below:

[image]

The points satisfying $x\le\sqrt{1-y^2}$ are those in the $\supset$-shaped region; those satisfying $y\le x$ are those to the right of the diagonal line; and the blue region is the intersection of those two sets.

Comment: "The equation $x=\sqrt{1−y^2}$ is the equation of the righthand half of the unit circle" Doesn't this contradict when you say later that: "the points satisfying $x\le \sqrt{1−y^2}$ are those in the ⊃-shaped region"?

Comment: @user1251385: No; the first statement implies the second.

Comment: Hmm... I think I've realized that I don't know how to graph $0\le x\le \sqrt{1-y^2}$.

Comment: Wait. I think I got it. Yes, I understand now.

Comment: I wasn't even graphing $0\le x\le \sqrt{1-y^2}$ with the right technique. It feels nice to kill two birds with one stone. :)

Comment: @user1251385: Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Start by graphing $y \le x$. This is fairly easy -- it's just the region under and including the line $y = x$.

Next, graph $x \le \sqrt{1-y^2}$. This is also pretty easy, and you have already done it.

The overlapping region is the result.

Comment: I think you may also need $1-y^2 \ge 0$ or $|y| \le 1$ to get a real square root

Comment: @Henry That was implicit in that the OP already mentioned that he graphed $0 \le x \le \sqrt{1-y^2}$. But yes.

Comment: Fair enough, but removing "$0 \le$" changes the area to be considered